# Can a 5V 1Ch Relay be switched with 4V?

Tags: relay, 5v

I have Arduino Mini Pro 5v and need to know if the Vcc will drive a 5v Relay. My Voltage output measure on the Vcc is 4.2v. Will the 5v Relay be triggered?

Comment: Read the datasheet of your selected relay and see what the minimum pickup voltage is.

Comment: Strauss - (a) Your question title says 4V, but the text says 4.2V. Why the difference? (b) 4.2V is an interesting number. Do you really mean that the power source will be a Li-Ion / LiPo battery and you have just given the typical fully-charged voltage of 4.2V? This aspect is important because such a battery doesn't stay at 4.2V, so there is more to consider, if your power source is a battery. || Can you please edit the question to include the datasheet link for the relay (as mentioned in the previous comment), as well as explain the actual power source, and explain regarding 4V / 4.2V.

Comment: If you want help, you must give us a link to the datasheet for the relay.

Comment: All switches must be specified by source voltage, impedance or current drive @ V? And load resistance and current or must Switch voltage.

Comment: @Transistor, you are right. Pickup voltage is 3.8v, thanks that helped a lot.

Comment: @SamGibson, it's a 5VDC power supply. My dropoff is that over the board.

Comment: @StraussBornman  Please edit this information [from the comment] into your answer.  Don't forget the datasheet link too.

Comment: @StraussBornman - Thanks for the replies. (a) As I asked (and *Nick Alexeev* reiterated) you need to *edit the question* and insert the new information, to explain your problem. (b) You said: "*My dropoff is that over the board.*" A 0.8V - 1V drop "over the board" raises new questions. I recommend that you add a wiring diagram & add photos of your hardware showing all your connections. Also explain where you measured the voltage drop. (c) I have now realised that your title of "5V 1Ch Relay" may not actually be a *relay*, but might be a *relay module* from Ebay/Amazon etc. Please add details.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the issue by driving the relay on the low side. Then you will have the full swing, as long as the I/O current is enough. If you’re still unsure of the current output of the Arduino, you can consider boosting the current using a FET or bipolar transistor to drive the relay.

Also, make sure to add a reverse-bias ‘freewheel’ diode across the coil. This absorbs the negative voltage spike when you remove power from the coil.

More: Your Arduino Pro 5V has a linear regulator on it to make internal 5V. If you’re feeding 5V as the raw supply (I’m guessing you are), the regulator will insert some dropout voltage, so internally the ATMega328 is seeing a lower voltage. You can overcome this in one of two ways: raise the raw supply to overcome the dropout, or bypass the regulator.

On the other hand, if, as suggested above, you drive the coil on the low side using a buffer (FET or bipolar transistor) then this becomes a non-issue.

Comment: Next to "as long as the I/O current is enough" it should also be checked if the output voltage of the driving pin will be driven low enough such that it is lower than the *must release voltage*.

Comment: What you said doesn’t make sense on a low-side drive.  The likely issue for the low Voh swing is the reg on the Arduino board. I didn’t want to get into a whole discussion of Voh/Vol vs. Ioh/Iol for the 328. That said, it should have plenty of drive (20-30mA), more so on the low side as is typical for CMOS. The information that’s missing about the coil is the DC resistance and the pull-in current. If there’s any question about the 328’s driving ability vs. the coil’s requirement, using a FET like a 2N7002 or BSS138 will overcome that limitation.